# How do I lauch a DatePicker Fragment on single click for EditText?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-edittext

I have one minor issue to fix with a DatePicker Fragment. The user clicks on an EditText line on the UI screen and that immediately launches a DatePcker fragment on the first click. The user selects a date and the code sets the date on the EditText line. The focus is returned to the EditText line with a blinking cursor.

Now if the user navigates away to another EditText line and then returns to the DatePicker EditText line to select a different date, it takes two clicks to launch the Picker again. The first click gets focus and the second click launches the Picker and I am trying to launch the Picker on the first click.  Note the emptiness test for "onFocusChange" is to ensure the fragment dialog does not launch when a date has been set and then an orientation change occurs.

partial Activity file:

```
...
fListenerEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            // The below line gets the Floating Label color to switch back to the primary Hint color.
            // Also allows the back button code to work correctly, to go back to the previous activity and clear
            // the soft keyboard with one press, not two.
            fListenerEditText.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // If fListernerEditText gains focus then launch DatePicker
            // else nothing is done is fListenerEditText loses focus.
            // Also the length() test is a test for emptiness;  that is, only display
            // the DatePicker dialog if the EditText is empty.  That way, if there is already a
            // a date set in the EditText line and an orientation change occurs, the new Activity
            // and Fragment won't re-launch the DatePicker dialog again because the length() test won't show empty.
            if (hasFocus && (fListenerEditText.getText().length() == 0)) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                // The below line gets the Floating Label color to switch back to the primary Hint color.
                // Also allows the back button code to work correctly, to go back to the previous activity and clear
                // the soft keyboard with one press, not two.
                fListenerEditText.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should use TextView instead of EditText

Comment: I chose the EditText because the user is selecting a date from the DatePicker Fragment and because the user can change their mind and select a different date later.  I thought TextView would only work if I was just displaying date.  Thoughts?

Comment: No, you can set setOnClickListener and it can work anytime user touch on textview